# How do you or a vector with a single bit in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have a vector, `my_vector`, and I want to `or` each bit with a single bit, `my_bit`, how can I do this?

In VHDL I would have to write something like:

```
foo <= (n-1 downto 0 => my_bit) || my_vector;
```

Is there an easier way of doing this in verilog?
I tried:

```
foo = my_bit | my_vector;
```

but it looks like it just does `{0...0,my_bit} | my_vector`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want to do `or`? Then you will only have 2 possible outputs: the original vector (if the bit is 0), and a vector of all 1's (if the bit is 1).

If so you can just use this conditional assignment:

```
assign my_vector = (my_bit == 0) ? my_vector : n'b111...1;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is:

```
foo = {n{my_bit}} | my_vector;
```